# Choosing gain to get desired system response

Tags: gain

I have to choose a gain so the step response fits a couple of criterias. The criterias are:

- Maximum overshoot 20%
- Settling time between 0.8s and 1.3s
- Rise time between 0.8s and 1.1s

At first I tried to find out the desired pole location. I used the following equations

- Overshoot: cos(arctan(y / (-x))) = 0.45595 (used Mp=e^(-pi*zeta/sqrt(1-zeta^2)) to find out the minimum damping ratio 0.45595)
- Settling time: x = -4.89 and x = -3.556 (used ln(0.02)/ts to find out required real part)
- Rise time: (pi + y / x) / y = 1.1 and (pi + y / x) / y = 0.8

The overlap of the area between those curves would be the desired pole location which looks like this.

[image: desired pole area]

Now, the block diagram looks like this

[image]

Its root locus looks like this (overlapped with the desired pole area)

[image]

As you can see, no gain would satisfy the requirements. Well, we can modify Kx a little bit and also add derivative and integral parts.

- Kx = Kp + Kd * s + Ki / s (Kx is supposed to look like this, it's a requirement)

What I did was adding a little Kd so the root locus goes through the desired pole area, then I'd pick a point on the root locus to get the required gain. (I chose Kp=1 and Kd=0.135 to plot the root locus)

[image]

So the total gain should be

- Kx = 5.29 * (1 + 0.135 * s)

right? Well, it does not work. I used stepinfo() to get the system response

```
    RiseTime: 0.3907
SettlingTime: 0.5625
 SettlingMin: 0.9084
 SettlingMax: 1.0152
   Overshoot: 1.5246
  Undershoot: 0
        Peak: 1.0152
    PeakTime: 0.8490
```

which is WAY off. Rise time isn't even close to the desired response and neither is settling time. What did I do wrong?

This is my code in Matlab

```
s = tf('s')
gain = 5.29;
Kp = 1;
Kd = 0.135;
Ki = 0;
Kx = parallel(tf(Kp, 1), parallel(tf([Kd, 0], 1), tf(Ki, [1, 0])))
p = 5/(s+5) * 1/s
pk = Kx * p;
h = 1;
figure(1)
rlocus(pk)
figure(2)
t = feedback(gain*pk, h);
step(t)
stepinfo(t)
```